# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC is raised when not allowing to overwrite the existing excel sheet

Tags: excel, exception

The above exception is raised when it prompt for overwrite already existing excel sheet with the same name and I Clicked NO in the prompt. Image is attached for clarification :

[image: Excel Prompt]

when I clicked the no it gives me above exception at the following lines of code :

```
workbook.SaveAs(outputFilePath, misValue, misValue, misValue,
            misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

I have used Microsoft Excel Library to do my processing. Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Click Yes instead :/  If you click No then Excel will of course tell you that the save failed.  You know how it does that, you don't need our help.  Automating Excel and still allowing the user to intervene is not a great idea.

Comment: so you mean i should not display the prompt to the user for that i have added the following line of code , excel.DisplayAlerts = false